# Разделить массив на подмассивы [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9] -> [[0,1],[2,3,4],[5,6], [7,8,9]]?

Tags: javascript, алгоритм, map-reduce

Имеется массив
`[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]`

в итоге нужно разбить на подмассивы
`[[0,1],[2,3,4],[5,6], [7,8,9]]`

Метод ниже разделяет исходный массив на подмассивы такого вида
`[[0,1],[2,3],[4,5],[6,7],[8,9]]`

```
   let arrayIndex = -1;

    const newArr = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9].reduce((final, curr, i) => {
      if (i%2 === 0) {
        final.push([curr])
        arrayIndex++;
      } else {
        final[arrayIndex].push(curr);
      }
      return final;
    }, []);
```

Как доработать метод, чтобы добиться ожидаемого результата?

Comment: `if i%5 == 0 or i%5 == 2`

Comment: А если будет 11 элементов?

Comment: Про 11 элементов в задаче нет ни слова. Логично предположить что будет неполный подмассив.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```js
let arrayIndex = -1;

const newArr = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9].reduce((final, curr, i) => {
  if (i % 5 === 0 || i % 5 === 2) {
    final.push([curr])
    arrayIndex++;
  } else {
    final[arrayIndex].push(curr);
  }
  return final;
}, []);

console.log(newArr);
```

Answer (score 4):

Условия по сохранению целостности оригинального массива нет, если есть - можно скопировать массив перед сплайсами, а так - вот:

```js
let arr = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9];
let result = [];
while (arr.length) 
  result.push(arr.splice(0, 2), arr.splice(0, 3))
console.log(JSON.stringify(result));
```

Или так:

```js
let arr = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9];
let result = [2,3,2,3].map(i => arr.splice(0, i));
console.log(JSON.stringify(result));
```

PS: это конечно не универсально

Comment: Вы на личном опыте этому всему научились, или есть какая-то книжка с секретными знаниями?)) Например, додуматься в push добавить два таких аргумента)

Comment: @OPTIMUSPRIME это ладно. А про второе я даже пару минут думал, но плюнул :) Это только опыт, причем в конкретном языке. ТО что работает в js  - совершенно не одно и тоже, что в python, например

Comment: @OPTIMUSPRIME я тоже так думаю это не человек под этим профилем какой то высший ИИ стоит :D .Ну то что он пишет то что творит с кодом это меня всегда удивляет и в каждом его  ответе есть что то новое лично для меня ))

Comment: @StrangerintheQ Надо еще циклический геттер сделать для [3,2].Будет еще универсальней

Comment: @splash58 я сначала написал что-то подобное, но получилось очень коряво и стёр

Comment: @OPTIMUSPRIME я просто много пишу всякую ерунду, вот и натаскался, книжки определенно есть, но всякие приемы я подсматривал и подсматриваю на всяких там codepen итд, ведь хорошо же, когда кода мало, я к этому пытаюсь стремиться в своих поделках (я не про промышленный код а про ответы тут и тот же codepen)

Comment: @OPTIMUSPRIME но в целом - геймдев и компьютерная графика хорошо вправляет мозги, я вот с тех пор как этим занимаюсь, на тот код  который писал до этого и задачи, которые решал- смотреть не могу, наверное так всегда, когда найдешь область, которая действительно по душе

Answer (score 3):

Для произвольного набора длин подмассивов

```js
const array = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10],
      chunk = [2,3], 
      al = array.length, cl = chunk.length;
var   ic = 0,
      newArr = [],
      i = 0;
while(i < al) {
    // перебираем по кругу массив длин (chunck)
    // и вырезаем подмассив с текущего индекса нужной длины методом slice  
    newArr.push(array.slice(i,i+chunk[ic]));
    i += chunk[ic];
    ic = (ic+1) % cl;
}
console.log(newArr)
```

Comment: А комментарии к коду будет ?

Comment: А что тут можно прокомментировать? :)

Comment: Можно прокомментировать код который внутри `while` не очень понятно лично мне.)

Comment: ждёмс ...........

Comment: доброе слово и кошке приятно :)