# Разбить массив на подмассивы

Tags: javascript

Дан массив **[1, 2, 3, 4, ..., n]** его надо разбить на *n* подмассивов, результат должен быть таким:
Например разбить **[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]** на **3** подмассива

```
[
 [1, 4, 7],
 [2, 5, 8],
 [3, 6],
]
```

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1040304

Comment: @XelaNimed не совсем та разбивка

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Вот так можно получить

```js
let a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8];
let subArrayCount = 3;
let result = a.reduce((acc, item, index)=> {
  if (acc[index%subArrayCount] == undefined) acc.push([]);
  acc[index%subArrayCount].push(item);
  return acc;
} , [])


console.log(result);
```

ну или покороче

```js
let s = 3;
let result = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8].reduce((a,t,i)=>(a[i%s]||a.push([]), a[i%s].push(t), a), []);
console.log(result);
```

или так с прототипами воспользовался ответом от @MoloF

```js
Array.prototype.chunk = function(s) {
    return this.reduce((a,t,i)=>(a[i%s]||a.push([]), a[i%s].push(t), a), [])
};

let result = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8].chunk(3);

console.log(result);
```

Ну продолжая тему минификации придумать такое.

```js
Array.prototype.p = Array.prototype.push;
Array.prototype.r = Array.prototype.reduce;
Array.prototype.c = function(s) {
    return this.r((a,t,i)=>(a[i%s]||a.p([]), a[i%s].p(t), a), [])
};

let result = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8].c(3);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Отличное решение, спасибо!